# golang conversion between function accepting abstract interface and function accepting struct implementation

Tags: go

An issue I met when creating a layer on top of different version of implementations. The goal is to abstract out the implementation details and the caller doesn't need to care which implementation we are using.

Please see the code example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/SyuirDQkH9Z)

^ The code can better explain the issue I met.

We have two version of Stream implementation `Stream1` and `Stream2`. They have a common interface `Stream`.

Both of them have a corresponding `BindStreamHandler` function accepting `StreamHandler1` or `StreamHandler2`.

We have a function `BindStreamHandler`, and a general implementation of `func StreamHandlerImpl(s Stream)`. No matter we use `Stream1` or `Stream2`, the general implementation is the same.

Now I face an issue downcasting `StreamHandlerImpl` (accepting abstract `Stream` to `StreamHandler1` (accepting `Stream1`).

---

Update:

I found [this version](https://play.golang.org/p/M21MZr3L_Sj) worked.

```
func BindHandler(h interface{}) {
    if Version == 1 {
        h1 := h.(StreamHandler1)
        BindStreamHandler1(h1)
    } else {
        h2 := h.(StreamHandler2)
        BindStreamHandler2(h2)
    }
}
```

But the signature of `BindHandler` becomes too weak :( I prefer using signature `func BindHandler(h StreamHandler)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to design your classes using class hierarchies (like Java) which is really not how Go tackles OO. I really suggest you design your code around interfaces rather than trying to mimic inheritance. Since we cannot speculate on why you have such types, below is a minimal code snippet which will make `BindHandler` maintain a stricter signature.

```
func BindHandler(h StreamHandler) {
    if Version == 1 {
        BindStreamHandler1(func(s Stream1) {
            h(s)
        })
    } else {
        BindStreamHandler2(func(s Stream2) {
            h(s)
        })
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U_IsBpmvdaz)

Comment: Thanks a lot! While I'm reading some golang library code, I come across this "function wrapper" style quite often. Didn't realize I should use it in this case.